# loading a new video with youtube api wont work

Tags: javascript, arrays, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

so i am trying to make a sort of youtube video request system. on my computer i have a file called video.txt with the id's of a few youtube videos in it. (each one gets their own line.) my code is as follows

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script>
    function addToList(file)
{
    var getVid = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getVid.open("GET", file, false);
    getVid.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(getVid.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(getVid.status === 200 || getVid.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = getVid.responseText;
                returnText = allText.replace( /\n/g, " " ).split( " " );
                vid.push.apply(vid, returnText);
                console.log(vid[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    getVid.send(null);
}


    //make the array
    var vid = []
    // create youtube player
    setInterval( getVid , 500 );
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player.loadVideoById({'videoId': 'qjlH7pQRK9I', 'startSeconds': 0});
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) { 
            addToList("video.txt");
            if (vid[0] == "") {
                vid.shift();
            }
            if (vid === undefined || vid.length == 0) {
                vid.push("qjlH7pQRK9I");
                player.loadVideoById({'videoId': vid[0], 'startSeconds': 0});
                vid.shift();
                } else {
                    player.cueVideoById( vid[0]);
                    player.playVideo();
                    vid.shift();
                }


            }

        }


</script>
```

Oh yeah. and whenever there is no video it plays a 10 second video of nothing. and it always starts with that. but then after that ends the next video should pop up and start playing... but it doesnt. instead i get this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrhJl.png

but there are no errors in the console... i'm probably doing something dumb... but i would love some help <3

Answer (score 0):

What's that setInterval doing there?  Definitely remove that.

I also changed where the text file is read.

I think this is the idea.

What do you want as the first video?  First 10 seconds of nothing, or not?

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>
  // array containing IDs of youtube videos
  var vid = [];
  // youtube player object
  var player;

  //Loads a text file with youtube IDs, pushes them to an array ( var vid )
  function loadIDsFromFile(file) {
    var getVid = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getVid.open("GET", file, false);
    getVid.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if(getVid.readyState === 4) {
        if(getVid.status === 200 || getVid.status == 0) {
          var allText = getVid.responseText;
          returnText = allText.replace( /\n/g, " " ).split( " " );
          vid.push.apply(vid, returnText);
          console.log(vid[0]);
        }
      }
    }
    getVid.send(null);
  }
  // the Youtube API is ready to use.  Let's load the text file here; no point in waiting
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    loadIDsFromFile("video.txt");
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
  // autoplay video
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.loadVideoById({'videoId': 'qjlH7pQRK9I', 'startSeconds': 0});
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
  // when video ends
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 0) { // last video stopped playing, let's load a next one and play it
      if (vid === undefined || vid.length == 0 || ! vid[0] ) {
        vid=["qjlH7pQRK9I"];    //default, "10 seconds of nothing" video
      }
      player.cueVideoById(vid[0]);
      player.playVideo();
      vid.shift();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: yeah first video is ten seconds of nothing. i have the setintervle there because i am useing a seperate program to write the text file and i have it put the id of the next video in the text file, and 10 seconds after delete it. meaning if a video is longer than 10 seconds, the next one wouldent get added to the array because it wouldent be in the text file any longer.

Comment: but after the 10 seconds of nothing it still tells me that i have invalid parameters. i just cant seem to find out why. And while it says invalid parameters if i right click the player and say copy the video URL... it gives me the right URL... so its like its just not loading properly.

Comment: If you use my code, your requirements are met.  Your problem is the code where you 're writing the file, and the setInterval.  Maybe you should edit your post and explain that.